# Drupal site blocks not showing correctly on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, drupal

[image]My Drupal site block 'bottom third'  is not showing up on Chrome. It shows everything as moved to the bottom 1st and bottom 2nd columns. On Safari it formats correctly. The theme is called 'premium' (note it is *not* a premium theme). Any idea?

Photos taken right now (after refreshing cache etc).
first image: safari browser

second image: chrome browser[image]

The theme block.tpl.php is:

```
   ?>
   <div id="<?php print $block_html_id; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php        print $attributes; ?>>

  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
 <?php if (!empty($block->subject)): ?>
   <h2 <?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $block->subject ?></h2>
 <?php endif;?>
 <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

 <div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
   <?php print $content ?>
 </div>
```

I have not applied any additional css or html etc to the site theme, I am just using it out of the box

My page source of the bottom blocks, copied from Chrome, is as below:

```
 </div> <!-- /.block --><div id="block-user-login" class="block block-user">

    <h2 >User login</h2>

  <div class="content">
   <form action="/node?destination=node" method="post" id="user-login-form"       accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-name">
  <label for="edit-name">Username <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
 <input type="text" id="edit-name" name="name" value="" size="15" maxlength="60" class="form-text required" />
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-password form-item-pass">
```

Password *

  [Create new account](/user/register)
  [Request new password](/user/password)

```
  </div> <!-- /.block --></div>
   <!-- /.region --></div>
              <div id="bottom2"><div class="region region-footer-second">
    <div id="block-follow-site" class="block block-follow">

    <h2 >Follow us on:</h2>

  <div class="content">
    <div class='follow-links clearfix site'><div class='follow-link-wrapper follow-link-wrapper-this-site'><a href="/rss.xml" class="follow-link follow-link-this-site follow-link-site" title="Follow us on This site (RSS)">This site (RSS)    </a>
   </div><div class='follow-link-wrapper follow-link-wrapper-facebook'><a   href="https://www.facebook.com/cinemmerse" class="follow-link follow-link-facebook follow-link-site" title="Follow us on Facebook">Facebook</a>
    </div><div class='follow-link-wrapper follow-link-wrapper-twitter'><a href="https://www.twitter.com/cinemmerse" class="follow-link follow-link-twitter follow-link-site" title="Follow us on Twitter">Twitter</a>
</div><div class='follow-link-wrapper follow-link-wrapper-linkedin'><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/wendydent" class="follow-link follow-link-linkedin follow-link-site" title="Follow us on LinkedIn">LinkedIn</a>
</div></div>  </div>

 </div> <!-- /.block --></div>
  <!-- /.region --></div>
              <div id="bottom3"><div class="region region-footer-third">
  <div id="block-twitter-block-1" class="block block-twitter-block">

     <h2 >Join the conversation at:</h2>

     <div class="content">
       <a href="https://twitter.com/@cinemmerse" class="twitter-timeline" data-widget-id="513805320578019329" data-theme="dark" data-tweet-limit="2" data-aria-polite="polite">Tweets by @cinemmerse</a>  </div>

</div> <!-- /.block --></div>
<!-- /.region --></div>
       </div>
   </div>

 <div id="copyright">
  Copyright &copy; 2016, . | Theme by  <a   href="http://www.devsaran.com">Devsaran</a>
 </div>
  <!--END footer -->
</div>  <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js">    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I like your note, but please include some code, images etc..we cannot help you with what you have

Comment: sure, thank you Ronnie. Images added. I am a beginner - am not sure which code you would like me to upload from the theme. I will post the block.tpl.php

Comment: the second image looks more correct than the first..what is the problem

Comment: This question is more html/css related than drupal related. Also people can not know what html are giving those print commands. It would be more useful if you could provide page source and as well CSS that is styling it.

Comment: Hi Ronnie, in the first screenshot (Safari browser) there are 3 blocks in the bottom. The tweets are the third column, correctly, as per the block settings. In the second screenshot (of Chrome browser) the tweets show up in the 2nd bottom block, not the 3rd bottom block.

Comment: Hi MilanG, thank you, I am a beginner -a Drupal site builder, and posted this as I'm perplexed why my browser is showing up differently to my site-  I don't really know CSS or Html. I have done a 'right click' on Chrome and copy-pasted the page source, I hope that may help - I will post it at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Easiest way would be to add this to jsfiddler or another similar fiddler to see this in action. Also you can try with another theme and check if you can repeat this issue.